# How do I connect the jupyter/all-spark-notebooks container with hadoop multi node cluster in docker

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Please be noted that I am novice in this. My requirement is to set up hadoop multi node cluster with spark and hive running over it in docker.

I had pulled a hadoop multi node cluster set up using uhopper/hadoop image and jupyter notebook to access a txt file I ingested in hdfs using pyspark. Now having jupyter in a seperate container and hadoop cluster in other containers, how do I tell jupyter notebook to run on the existing hadoop cluster?

Kindly suggest any better method to meet my requirement.